# C++11 Vector::data() equivalent in C++98

Tags: c++, vector, c++98

## **Edit:**

After reading the comments and the answers, I understand that the following could be a legitimate implementation in C++98:

```
class Environ {

private:

    std::vector<char*> data;

public:

    Environ(const CHAR *environmentBlock)
    {
        for (const CHAR *s = environmentBlock; *s; s += strlen(s) + 1)
            data.push_back(strdup(s));

        data.push_back(NULL);
    }

    char** Data(){
        return &data[0]; // data should have at least one item (NULL)
    }

    ~Environ()
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); i++)
            free(data[i]);
    }
};
```

The above should work on C++98?
What worries me is depending on &data[0].

=============================================================

## **Original question:**

I need to create a char** environ like type - an array of strings.
The input is a string that uses '\0' as delimiters, and it is terminated with double '\0'.

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
    Environ(const CHAR *environmentBlock)    {
        size_t count = 0;
        for (const CHAR *s = environmentBlock; *s; s += strlen(s) + 1)
            count++;

        // Allocate 1 extra entry for the last NULL entry.
        CHAR** data = new CHAR*[count + 1];

        CHAR **entry = data;
        size_t length = 0;
        for (const CHAR *s = environmentBlock; *s; s += length + 1, entry++)
        {
            length = strlen(s);
            *entry = strndup(s, length);
        }
        *entry = NULL;
    }
```

On C++11 std::vector has the data() method, which could create it for me in one iteration - I just
need to create vector<char*>, fill it, and get the data representation of it.

Is there something similar on C++98?

Thanks

Comment: [The `data` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) essentially returns a pointer to the first element of the vector. Which you can get yourself with e.g. `&the_vector[0]`.

Comment: I don't really understand your code, but you don't need `data()` if you use `std::transform` or the like. Don't expect to be able to insert elements (change its size) in the vector via `data()`, you can't

Comment: The one caveat when using `&vector[0]` is that the vector cannot be empty.  That is the one big difference between `data()` and `&vector[0]`, in that `data()` works for empty vectors.

Answer (score 0):

It's not almost same. The `vector<char*>.data()` returns a char** but before the vector gets destroyed you must free the content allocated by `strndup`to avoid memory leak

`CHAR** data = new CHAR*[count + 1];` your creating a `char*` array. you must free it as well as free `strndup`. It's up to you which option is prefered

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of what to use instead of `std::vector::data<T>` when a compiler does not supply this (which I think is incorrect but I could be wrong), I have found the following implementations work.

```
#include <vector>
struct T{}; // just to have a type to use
int main() {
  std::vector<T> v;
  v.push_back(T());
  T* p1=v.data();
  T* p2=&*v.begin();
  T* p3==&v[0];
  T* p4=&v.front();
  // p1==p2==p3==p4 should hold.
}
```